# How to write a t-sql query to display current month calendar? Please help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to write a t-sql query to display current month calendar? Please help..
this is my query

```
declare @start int
declare @day int
declare @space varchar(100)
declare @nodays int
select @start=1
select @space=''
select @nodays=datediff(dd,getdate(),dateadd(mm,1,getdate()))
select @day=case datename(dw,cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-' +cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-' +cast(day(getdate()) as varchar(10))) when 'Sunday' then 1 when 'Monday' then 2 when 'tuesday' then 3 when 'wednesday' then 4 when 'thursday' then 5 when 'friday' then 6 when 'saturday' then 7 end
while(@start<=@nodays)
    if(@day=1)
        if(len(@space)=0)
            select @space=cast(@start as varchar(10))
        else
            select @space=@space+' '+
            case when len(cast(@start as varchar(10)))=1 
            then ' ' 
            else '' 
            end +
            cast(@start as varchar(10))
    else
        if(len(@space)=0)
            select @space=@space+ 
            replicate(char(10),@start) +
            case when len(cast(@start as varchar(10)))=1 
            then ' ' 
            else '' 
            end +
            cast(@start as varchar(10))
        else
            select @space=@space+char(10) + case when len(cast(@start as varchar(10)))=1 then ' ' else '' end +cast(@start as varchar(10))
    select @start=@start+1
print @space+char(10)
```